# Most efficient way to "nibble" the first line of text from a text document then resave it in python

Tags: python, text-files, deque

I have a text document that I would like to repeatedly remove the first line of text from every 30 seconds or so.

I have already written (or more accurately copied) the code for the python resettable timer object that allows a function to be called every 30 seconds in a non blocking way if not asked to reset or cancel.

[Resettable timer in python repeats until cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651931/resettable-timer-in-python-repeats-until-cancelled/15652019?noredirect=1#15652019)

(If someone could check the way I implemented the repeat in that is ok, because my python sometimes crashes while running that, would be appreciated :))

I now want to write my function to load a text file and perhaps copy all but the first line and then rewrite it to the same text file. I can do this, this way I think... but is it the most efficient ?

```
def removeLine():

    with open(path, 'rU') as file:
        lines = deque(file)
        try:
            print lines.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            print "Nothing to pop?"
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lines)
```

This works, but is it the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) with `inplace=True`:

```
import fileinput

def removeLine():
    inputfile = fileinput.input(path, inplace=True, mode='rU')
    next(inputfile, None)  # skip a line *if present*
    for line in inputfile:
        print line,  # write out again, but without an extra newline
    inputfile.close()
```

`inplace=True` causes `sys.stdout` to be redirected to the open file, so we can simply 'print' the lines.

The `next()` call is used to skip the first line; giving it a default `None` suppresses the `StopIteration` exception for an empty file.

This makes rewriting a *large* file more efficient as you only need to keep the `fileinput` readlines buffer in memory.

I don't think a `deque` is needed at all, even for your solution; just use `next()` there too, then use `list()` to catch the remaining lines:

```
def removeLine():
    with open(path, 'rU') as file:
        next(file, None)  # skip a line *if present*
        lines = list(file)
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lines)
```

but this requires you to read all of the file in memory; don't do that with large files.

Comment: +1 for `fileinput`, you may wanna comment on how standard output is redirected to the file